# Communication between add-on script and a page packaged within my firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an add-on for firefox. I am using the new SDK to do that. I real about ports and what not for communication between add-on script and content scripts. My add-on performs some processing and then comes up with some results. I am trying to present these results to the user in a new tab whose html/css/js is packaged with the add on itself. I am not sure how to communicate the results to the page.

Thanks

PS: I can do that comfortably with a panel but I am not sure how to do that with a new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured out how to do it. I thought I should write the answer here in case someone else is stuck at the same issue!

The trick is to open a new tab containing your page, and on "ready" event, you attach a ContentScript or a ContentScriptFile. The attach() method returns a worker that you can use to communicate back and forth between the add-on script and the ContentScript. There might be a more efficient way to do this, but I got this working for me no problems.

```
function attachContentScript(){
    var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
        ContentScriptFile: self.data.url("myContentScript.js")
    });
    //Now you can commmunicate using worker and the content script
    //using port    
}
tabs.open(self.data.url("myPage.html"));
tabs.on("ready", attachContentScript)
```

Comment: The relevant documentation is now located here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

Answer (score -1):

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
url= self.data.url("yourpage.html");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open(url);
```

[Page on SDK documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/open-a-web-page.html)

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I was asking for